# How do I hang a 500lb bed swing?

Tags: carpentry, engineering

Could someone please tell me what kind of support is needed to hang a 500 pound porch bed swing?  The 500 pounds also includes the weight of people on the swing.

Comment: Didn't the swing come with installation instructions?

Comment: How many anchor points? How far apart are they?  hanging 500lbs from a single anchor is different the spreading it across 4 points over 10'

Comment: A picture or diagram of the swing and your porch would also help.  If it's under tension like a hammock, there may well be forces much higher than 500lb involved.

Comment: I don't have enough info to give a more complete answer, but putting large lag screws directly into the structural elements of the house (joists) is usually a good start. Of course you have to be careful not to weaken the house with too-many or too-large holes.